# How to add the border to the pie chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, lightningchart

In lightningchartJS how can I add border to my pie chart? Where a whole chart has a border as well as the individual category also has a border.

```
pie.setLabelFormatter(SliceLabelFormatters.NamePlusRelativeValue).setSliceStrokeStyle({color: ColorRGBA(200, 200, 200)})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PieChart.setSliceStrokeStyle](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/piechart.html#setslicestrokestyle) method to set a border that is used for all Slices in the chart.

```js
pieChart.setSliceStrokeStyle(
  new SolidLine( {
    thickness: 3,
    fillStyle: new SolidFill( { color: ColorRGBA( 200, 200, 200 ) } )
  } )
)
```